# Dynamic Sized Image And Caption Box?

Tags: css

I'm looking for the best practise method of making what I have pictured below. I want the caption box to take as little space as possible and the image to take up all the available space. The container can have set height and width, though I'd prefer it if could be dynamic.

I'm looking to do this with just HTML and CSS.

```
<div id="exampleBox">
   <img>
   <span></span>
</div>
```

[image: Example of desired result]
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this if your `exampleBox` has a set height.

Simply minus the height of the caption from your `exampleBox` height.

Then use this value to set the height of the image.

```js
var exampleBoxHeight = document.getElementById('exampleBox').clientHeight;
var captionHeight = document.getElementById('caption').clientHeight;

var imgHeight = (exampleBoxHeight - captionHeight);
var boxImg = document.getElementById('boxImg').height = imgHeight;
```

```css
#exampleBox {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#exampleBox img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#exampleBox span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="exampleBox">
   <img id="boxImg" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
   <span id="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit modo ligula eget dolor.</span>
</div>
```

Here is a codepen link for you to play about with too: [Codepen Links](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdWobx)

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Figure` with a ratio (width/height = 2/1), set all childs as `position: absolute`, for `img` `height: 100%` for box fitting;
Also, you can add any ratio. But it depends on `Figure`'s width, so it will be declared.

```css
/* start boilerplate */
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
/* end boilerplate */


.Figure {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 40vw; /* Just for demo, you should declare any width */
  margin: 10px;
}
.Figure:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 50%; /* Ratiobox hack: width / height === 2 / 1 */
}

.Figure__img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.Figure__cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.Figure__cover--top_bottom {
  background-position: 0% 100%;
}
.Figure__cover--bottom_top {
  background-position: 100% 0%;
}

.Figure__caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- with img -->
<figure class="Figure">
  <img class="Figure__img" src="http://www.1wallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/Abstract/FTP2/1280x720/Red%20Abstract%20Wallpapers%20HD%2005%201280x720.jpg">
  <figcaption class="Figure__caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nemo consectetur, fuga laborum officiis ea impedit reprehenderit iste autem blanditiis nostrum</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="Figure">
  <img class="Figure__img" src="http://www.1wallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/Abstract/FTP2/1280x720/Red%20Abstract%20Wallpapers%20HD%2005%201280x720.jpg">
  <figcaption class="Figure__caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </figcaption>
</figure>
<!-- /with img -->

<!-- with background-image -->
<figure class="Figure">
  <div class="Figure__cover Figure__cover--bottom_top" style="background-image: url(http://www.1wallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/Abstract/FTP2/1280x720/Red%20Abstract%20Wallpapers%20HD%2005%201280x720.jpg)"></div>
  <figcaption class="Figure__caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="Figure">
  <div class="Figure__cover Figure__cover--top_bottom" style="background-image: url(http://www.1wallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/Abstract/FTP2/1280x720/Red%20Abstract%20Wallpapers%20HD%2005%201280x720.jpg)"></div>
  <figcaption class="Figure__caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi nemo consectetur, fuga laborum officiis ea impedit reprehenderit iste autem blanditiis nostrum</figcaption>
</figure>
<!-- with /background-image -->
```

Comment: If <img> tag is not required, you can use emtpy div with background-image: url(); and background-size: cover;

Comment: background-image is more flexible - you can set background-position;